# Crucial dram showing unknown manufacturer

Tags: memory

I have bought a 16GB ddr5 4800hz ram from a Vietnam store. When I plugged the ram to my laptop and check with memtest86 and cruicial scanner they show me "unknown" manufacturer (please see the picture).

[image: img]

But if I check with cpuz it show Module Manuf. Crucial technology; DRAM Manuf. Micron technology.

Please help me to verify it is real or fake.
Thank you

Comment: Real or fake what? There are only three RAM manufacturers in the world [Crucial RAM is made by Micron, the others are Samsung & Hynix], so it has to be one of them. The part number gives https://uk.crucial.com/memory/ddr5/ct16g48c40s5 which matches just fine.

Comment: Furthermore, if the module works, and the system detects 16GB, then it has to be real. You didn't even purchase the memory in a region where fake computer parts are very likely

Comment: I'm worry that a fake manufacturer make the fake ram, like Dior fake, Chanel fake, Hermes fake,... Of course they can do the work, but fake is still fake and may cause issues in the future. Is it a case?

Comment: To repeat… there are only three factories in the entire world that can make RAM. "Fake RAM" is not an issue in the world, because of this.

Comment: But let assume you are right, then why both software showing "unknown" manufacturer? Please explain to me

Comment: @Tetsujin You might want to take a look at this wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_fabrication_plants) and search for `DRAM`. One of the first matches is ChangXin Memory Technologies, based in China.

Comment: SoT - sorry, but that kind of xenophobia doesn't really help. Most of it's made in China anyway. @doneal24 - too small to count yet. I suppose I should have said 'companies' not 'factories'. If you're going to go down that route you need to also check who owns who & whose supply chain it's in. Not something I've time or patience to track for myself. My info came from Crucial themselves, though I can't now find the link.

Comment: Try to see what says the [Crucial System Scanner](https://www.crucial.com/store/systemscanner).

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't tell us exactly what you bought in "I have bought a 16GB ddr5 4800hz ram" - then you can't say it's a fake.

Fake would imply the shop sold you for example "Crucial Technology" DRAM, and you've a proof it's not.
The packaging should inform you.

But the fact some tools can't read the brand or not is another problem, it could be the tool itself or the erroneous info the manufacturer put (or forgot to put) in the product.

Much more, as long as it's not patented or copyrighted, anyone is authorized to manufacture the same products.

Like (common) screws, nuts and bolts.

Those aren't "fakes", but different brands, and it also doesn't mean those "fakes" are worse or better than the ones you know - and which show a reputed brand.

I'd highly recommend you this **deep** YouTube channel about industrial manufacturing electronics subjects, often in Asia but not always:

https://www.youtube.com/@Asianometry/videos

If you bought this DRAM at a reduced cost, and every measure shows you it's working plainly, then please simply enjoy your decision and your product?

Comment: It's also very likely that it being a brand new DDR5 type memory the software being used to identify it hasn't been updated yet to recognize such modules.

Comment: I agree @ChanganAuto, I didn't notice but those are recent - software may not recognize them. Thank you! And this kind of product is made by only a couple of factories: Samsung, Hynix, Micron... but tens of brands sell them under a different name. Found a clear article about this [here](https://www.cgdirector.com/ram-brands-matter/)